# Attach function to html5 video onended using Vuejs2

Tags: html, vuejs2, html5-video

I'm trying to loop a video on vuejs2, I'm using the standard `<video>` tag from html5.

The way I need it to loop is that after the first time it has been executed it needs to loop from 17s to the end.

Since the standard `<video loop>` starts from the beginning, I've found myself trying to use `<video v-bind:onended="function_name_here">` , but it seems not to work.

I've tryed the following:

```
v-bind:onended="function()"
v-bind:onended="this.function()"
onended="this.function"
onended="function"
```

I am pretty sure it's not a problem inside the `function()` because the first line is a `console.log("success!")` I've set there in order to check the function is reached. (I've also double checked by controlling the  `document.findElementById("mainVideo").onended` via console during runtime.

Can anyone help me with this?

P.S. If you can provide an alternative to the manual implementation(e.g. loopFrom) it's very nice but I'm also planning to do stuff at the end of non-looping videos, so I still need to access the `onended` event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uses `v-bind:ended` instead of `v-bind:onended`.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    onEnd: function () {
      console.log('test on Ended')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<video controls
    src="https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4"
    poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/title_anouncement.jpg?x11217"
    width="620" @ended="onEnd()">

Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos, 
but don't worry, you can <a href="https://archive.org/details/BigBuckBunny_124">download it</a> 
and watch it with your favorite video player!

</video>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!
That was very helpful!